# Вывод имён и фамилий студентов из списка

Tags: файлы, golang

Получается вывести только классы, однако вместе с ними должны быть имена и фамилии студетнов, учащихся
в них. Пробовал через (map). Компилятор баги не вывел, но при запуске терминал был пустым, а выход из программы был нормальным (0).
student.csv файл имеет следущее содержание:
Фамилия, Имя, класс. Например: Ivanov, Dima, 9b.
В терминал выводятся только классы:8a, 9b, 4e, 7c, и т.д
Помогиет пожалуйста вывести классы вместе с учениками как здесь: Ivanov, Dima, 9b

```
package main

import(
   "fmt"
   "bufio"
   "os"
   "strings"
   "strconv"
)

  type(
       tGroup struct{
       Year int
       Index rune
       }
       tStudent struct{
         Fname string
         Lname string
         Group tGroup
       }
   )

func main() {

fin, err := os.Open("students.csv")
if err != nil{
    fmt.Print(err)
    return
}
defer fin.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fin)

var student tStudent
var data[] tStudent


// Конвертируем данные в формат struct tStudent

// Считываем строки из файла students.csv, конвертируем 
// их в tStudent и собираем в data []tStudent
for scanner.Scan(){
    line := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
    student.Fname, student.Lname = line[1], line[0]
    gr := []rune(line[2])
    student.Group.Index = gr[len(gr)-1]
    gr = gr[:len(gr)-1]
    student.Group.Year, _ = strconv.Atoi(string(gr))
    data = append(data, student)
}

list := make(map[tGroup]int)
for _, student := range data{
    list[student.Group]++
}

for gr := range list{
    fmt.Printf("%3d%c\n", gr.Year, gr.Index)
}

}
```

Comment: А есть причина, почему вы не используете [`encoding/csv`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/)?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так поменять

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
    student.Fname, student.Lname = line[1], line[0]
    gr := []rune(line[2])
    student.Group.Index = gr[len(gr)-1]
    gr = gr[:len(gr)-1]
    student.Group.Year, err = strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSpace(string(gr)))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("on student: %s, error :%v", student.Fname, err)
    }
    data = append(data, student)
}
```

Внимание на использование strings.TrimSpace
У вас в функцию Atoi передавалась строка с пробелами... не стоит злоупотреблять подчёркиванием.

ИМХО очень странно для разбора конвертить в слайс рун а потом обратно в строку...
И ещё у вас map с ключём структура, а вы можете представить как оно работает